# Avoiding WeakEventManager and memory leaks on short lived viewmodels

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, weakeventmanager

I have long living models with properties displayed using a view. 
The DataContext on my view is a ViewModel with a short lifespan.

Examples include row viewmodels in lists.

To avoid memory leaks the viewmodels subscribe to models using `System.Windows.WeakEventManager`.

If I were to subscribe normally the long living model would keep the viewmodel alive.

Using the WeakEventManager in about every viewmodel seems very cumbersome.
The usecase looks like a standard usecase for WPF. Am I missing a fundamental concept of WPF or C# that would help me writing better code here?

Here is a minimal Example that Illustrates what I do right now.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //building would take place in a factory method
        DataContext = new ShortLivedViewModel(new LongLivingModel());
    }
}

public class ShortLivedViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _myText;

    public ShortLivedViewModel(LongLivingModel model)
    {
        model.SomeEvent += SomeEventHandler;
        WeakEventManager<LongLivingModel, EventArgs>.AddHandler(model, nameof(LongLivingModel.SomeEvent),
            SomeEventHandler);
    }

    public string MyText
    {
        get => _myText;
        set
        {
            _myText = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MyText)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private void SomeEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //The actual update content would come from the event args
        MyText = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
    }
}

public class LongLivingModel
{
    //the event does not matter too much so I omit the implementation that causes it
    public EventHandler<EventArgs> SomeEvent = delegate { };
}
```

My question is if there is a less cumbersome way of subscribing to a long living object from a short living object. Or if there is some facility in WPF that I am missing for this.

It strikes me that this would be the standard case.
What I played around with is adding an `IDisposable` interface but that just leaves me with tacking when to call dispose so I can unsubscribe.

What I am looking for may be a combination of telling the GC that subscriptions do not count for the lifetime of the viewmodel and unsubscribing on destruction - or an even better solution.

Comment: Combination? If you don't know when to unsubscribe, you should use the weak event pattern. The other option would to unsubscribe explicitly using the =- syntax. You may for example implememt the IDisposable interface in the view model class and dipose it when the view is unloaded by handling the Unloaded event.

Comment: Could the long living viewmodel not push changes to the child viewmodels without events? If it needs to update the `MyText` Property it could just do that directly?

Comment: @bic technically yes. The long living instance would still have a reference. I am not sure if I could use this subtle difference to the event system as a way to address my issues.

Comment: The long living instance would responsible for getting rid of its references when the child is no longer needed - the child can inform the parent when it is done/removed etc.

Comment: @bic I think you are right - my predicament is an architectural failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the parent viewmodel should be responsbile for getting rid of references.

This is a simple example that pushes an update to each child viewmodel. When a child needs to be cleaned up, it tells the parent to remove its reference.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //building would take place in a factory method
        DataContext = new LongLivingModel();
        LongLivingModel.AddChild();
        LongLivingModel.AddChild();
    }
}

public class ShortLivedViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly LongLivingModel longLivingModel;

    public ShortLivedViewModel(LongLivingModel longLivingModel){
        this.longLivingModel = longLivingModel;
    }

    private string _myText;

    public string MyText
    {
        get => _myText;
        set
        {
            _myText = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MyText)));
        }
    }

    public void Remove(){
        longLivingModel.Remove(this);
    }

    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
}

public class LongLivingModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ShortLivedViewModel> ChildViewModels { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ShortLivedViewModel>();

    public void AddChild(){
        ChildViewModels.Add(new ShortLivedViewModel(this));
    }

    public void RemoveChild(ShortLivedViewModel shortLivedViewModel) {
        ChildViewModels.Remove(shortLivedViewModel);
    }

    public void PushToChildren(){
        foreach(ShortLivedViewModel shortLivedViewModel in ChildViewModels){
            shortLivedViewModel.MyText = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        }
    }
}
```